# Getting Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded when filtering a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I'm trying to write a simple (supposedly!) piece of code which filters the strings in an array as the user types.

Here's a cut down version of what I've done.

To briefly explain I have two components which interact with each other.

1. `FilterExample` which contains the list of strings to be filtered
2. `MySearchBar` which is passed the list of strings to be filtered via the prop `elementsToFilter`.

When the search text changes in `MySearchBar` it calculates which indices of `elementsToFilter` should still be displayed and passes these back to `FilterExample` via the callback `onFilterTextChanged`

I cannot explain why the following error appearing in an infinite loop, and how one of the dependency array(i.e. `currentFilterIndices` and `fruits`) of useEffect would change on each render

```
Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls
setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array,
or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
    in FilterExample (at src/index.js:9)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)
```

[image: Edit infinite-hook-calls]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import MySearchBar from "./MySearchBar";

/** Basic example of a list of strings filterable using PilzDashboardActionBar*/
function FilterExample() {
  const fruits = [
    "Apples ",
    "Oranges ",
    "Bananas ",
    "Pears ",
    "Peaches ",
    "Grapes "
  ];

  const [currentFilterIndices, setCurrentFilterIndices] = useState([
    ...Array(fruits ? fruits.length : 0).keys()
  ]);
  const [stringsToDisplay, setStringsToDisplay] = useState(fruits);

  //When the filter indices are sent in a callback from MySearchBar I
  //filter the list of strings.f
  useEffect(() => {
    setStringsToDisplay(
      fruits.filter((currString, currIndex) => {
        return currentFilterIndices.includes(currIndex);
      })
    );
  }, [currentFilterIndices, fruits]);

  //This calls back from the MySearchBar when the user types filtered text into it.
  const handleActionBarFilterTextChanged = filteredElementIndicesFromSearchBar => {
    setCurrentFilterIndices(filteredElementIndicesFromSearchBar);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <MySearchBar
        elementsToFilter={stringsToDisplay}
        onFilterTextChanged={handleActionBarFilterTextChanged}
      />
      {stringsToDisplay}
    </>
  );
}

export default FilterExample;
```

```
import React from "react";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

function MySearchBar(props) {
  //Destructure props
  const { elementsToFilter, onFilterTextChanged } = props;

  const handleSearchTextChange = currSearchText => {
    let filterIndices = [];
    elementsToFilter.forEach((currItem, currIndex) => {
      if (currItem.toUpperCase().includes(currSearchText.toUpperCase())) {
        filterIndices.push(currIndex);
      }
    });

    onFilterTextChanged(filterIndices);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        onChange={event => {
          handleSearchTextChange(event.target.value);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default MySearchBar;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are creating a new fruit array on every render.

Since the useEffect compares the fruits array shallowly, it will trigger a rerender if the array changed.

Since its a new one every render, it causes an infinity loop. Just move the array generation out of the function component or wrap it with useMemo.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import MySearchBar from "./MySearchBar";

  const fruits = [
    "Apples ",
    "Oranges ",
    "Bananas ",
    "Pears ",
    "Peaches ",
    "Grapes "
  ];

/** Basic example of a list of strings filterable using PilzDashboardActionBar*/
function FilterExample() {

  const [currentFilterIndices, setCurrentFilterIndices] = useState([
    ...Array(fruits ? fruits.length : 0).keys()
  ]);
  const [stringsToDisplay, setStringsToDisplay] = useState(fruits);

  //When the filter indices are sent in a callback from MySearchBar I
  //filter the list of strings.f
  useEffect(() => {
    setStringsToDisplay(
      fruits.filter((currString, currIndex) => {
        return currentFilterIndices.includes(currIndex);
      })
    );
  }, [currentFilterIndices, fruits]);

  //This calls back from the MySearchBar when the user types filtered text into it.
  const handleActionBarFilterTextChanged = filteredElementIndicesFromSearchBar => {
    setCurrentFilterIndices(filteredElementIndicesFromSearchBar);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <MySearchBar
        elementsToFilter={stringsToDisplay}
        onFilterTextChanged={handleActionBarFilterTextChanged}
      />
      {stringsToDisplay}
    </>
  );
}

export default FilterExample;
```